# Editing documents in Sharepoint on Internet Explorer 9 causes hang/freeze

Tags: freeze, sharepoint, internet-explorer-9

I recently downloaded and installed IE 9 on my Win 7 x64 laptop (Thinkpad T400).

Editing documents in Sharepoint (rich HTML editor) results in the browser hanging (screen turns white, cursor to egg timer).

Tabbing between web page *sometimes* works, other times the tab changes but the web page that was tabbed to doesn't render on screen.

I did have the IE9 platform preview installed, which I've since uninstalled and rebooted the computer, and have also disabled all add-ons.

I'd be interested to know if anyone has experienced similar issues.

Comment: I'm also using IE 9 RC with SharePoint 2010 editing. I have not experienced freezeing while editing in SharePoint, though I've seen the behavior you are talking about on other websites.